# How big (string) can the member be in Redis GEOADD

Tags: redis

the GEOADD call has the following signature:

GEOADD key longitude latitude member [longitude latitude member ...]

I cannot find in the documentation about the max size of the member (string length)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of any Redis string up to and including v4 is "limited" to 0.5GB.